# Javascript / jQuery : Split content in two parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure if this can be accomplished with Javascript and any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Here is a scenario:  Let's say I have content (all text), that's 6 paragraphs long.  The content is dynamically pulled from the database at once (meaning all 6 paragraphs are outputted through a single variable, so no way for me to change that).

What I need to do is, show the first two paragraphs at the top of the page, then show some other content, then show the remaining paragraphs below the other content.

So, content = 6 Paragraphs

```
Paragraph One
Paragraph Two

SOME OTHER COOL STUFF IN BETWEEN

Paragraph Three
Paragraph ...
Paragraph Six
```

Is it possible to split this content with Javascript.  The paragraphs are outputted inside p tags.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a sample of the "content" so we know what constitutes a paragraph.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, please tag it with `[jquery]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    <p>Paragraph 4</p>
    <p>Paragraph 5</p>
    <p>Paragraph 6</p>
    <div id="cool">SOME OTHER COOL STUFF IN BETWEEN</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#wrapper > p').slice(2).appendTo('#wrapper');
```

**CSS**

```
#cool { font-size:20px; color:red; }
```

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/KZm5X/

Answer (score 2):

If it's one long string, unless there's a delimeter I don't see a way of separating. If they are in paragraphs tags already, you can use something like jQuery and `.append` after the second paragraph tag the content you want using `:eq(1)` selector.

Comment: Yep it's one long string being outputted in individual p tags ... i will give .append a shot thanks!

Comment: If you need help or an example just comment back and ill post the code. Should be straight forward though and the jquery site has plenty of examples. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks guys I got this to work with: $('#wrapper > p').slice(2).appendTo('#wrapper'); from @Sime Vidas but all your suggestion pointed to this solution

Answer (score 2):

If each paragraph is wrapped in a p tag then you could do something like this (example is significantly with jquery but wouldn't be too bad with just javascript)

content:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script>
$('#wrapper:nth-child(2)').append("SOME OTHER COOL STUFF IN BETWEEN");
</script>
```

as regular javascript

```
<script>
var p3 = document.getElementById('#wrapper').childNodes[2];
var text = document.createElement("p");
text.innerHTML = "SOME OTHER COOL STUFF IN BETWEEN";
p3.insertBefore(text,p3);
</script>
```

Comment: This may just do the trick and I'm using jQuery exclusively for this site, so even better. Trying now ...

Comment: Some telepathy going on here :)

Comment: With [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore), shouldn't that not be called on `p3`, but on its parent?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say you were using a library, so here is how to achieve it without a library.

```
var p = document.getElementById('my-container').getElementsByTagName('p'),
    newDiv = document.createElement('div');

p.parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, p[2]);
```

Comment: ah, you beat me too it, added my version to my comment

Comment: sorry I should have specified that i can use jQuery, updated the post now and did get this to work finally.  Thanks for you help!